# How to use <ngt-buffer-geometry>

Tags: angular, three.js

I'm trying to understand how to convert some code in three.js to Angular three and not quite understanding; e.g.

When trying to use:

```
<ngt-buffer-geometry>
```

In three.js (from their example code) you would draw a line as follows;

```
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
const points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
```

How do I translate that into Angular Three?

Then, in general: It seems a function such as setFromPoints() can't be used in ngt. Is there a particular way to think about how to convert such code from three.js to ngt?

When using plane-geometry for example the below works, but I seem to be struggling with ngt-buffer-geometry;

```
<ngt-plane-geometry *args="[5, 5]" />
```

*args, ngt-buffer-attribute